# spring: share value between annotated beans like jsf applicationscope

Tags: jsf, scope, annotations, spring-4

I am working on a project with jsf 2.2 on the web side and spring 4 on the business side. I have a web filter which receives a parameter from the request url. From this parameter I have to connect to a database. There are cases where there are different databases possible, so depending on the parameter I have to initiate a different database connection. The web filter looks like this:

```
@Component
public final class SecurityFilter implements Filter
{
    @Autowired
    private CommonEao commonEao;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;

    String instance = req.getParameter("instance");

    //I would like to have something here like:
    // springContext.addParameter("instance", instance);

    String company = req.getParameter("company");

    commonEao.getConfiguration(company);
    ... Do stuff
    }
}
```

How does it works? The commonEao contains methods to make queries to the database (JPA/Eclipselink...). At initialization, no entityManager is present in commonEao since it is injected in SecurityFilter before the doFilter is executed when an url is requested. After the url is requested, the instance of the database to use is known through the 'instance' request parameter.

When the method commonEao.getConfiguration(company) is invoked, the first thing that should happen is to create an entity Manager:

```
@Repository
public final class CommonEao extends AbstractEao
{

    public final void getConfiguration(final String company) 
    {
        if (entityManager == null)
        {

            //I would like to have something here like:
            // String instance = springContext.getParameter("instance");
            createEntityManager(instance);
        }
        else ...

    }
}
```

As you can see, when the first time the url is requested, no entityManager exists and it needs to be created based on the instance name provided by the request. Based on the instance name the properties files containing database connection parameters will be used the call the Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory functionality... etc etc... :)

What is the idea? The idea that I had, as you can see in my comments, is to put a parameter in some global context/container that is available for all Spring beans. This idea comes from the JSF world, where you can create a managed bean, annotate it with applicationscope, define a variable in it, and access this variable from any jsf managed bean through injecting the application scoped bean with the managedproperty annotation:

```
@ManagedBean
public final class SomeJsfBean
{

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{applicationBean}")
    private ApplicationBean applicationBean;

    private void method() 
    {
        applicationBean.setInstanceName("instance");
    }
}

@ManagedBean
public final class AnotherJsfBean
{

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{applicationBean}")
    private ApplicationBean applicationBean;

    private void method() 
    {
        String instance = applicationBean.getInstanceName();
    }
}
```

I have some restrictions though. I want to use a global object of Spring. I don't have any XML config in my project. Spring is configured like this and nothing more:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = { "megan.fox.is.hot", "as.is.lindsay.lohan" })
public class SpringConfiguration
{

}
```

I have looked in many places, something I found was fetching a property from PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and stuff like that, but I didn't understand how it works and mainly it looks way too complex for what i need: just sharing one variable.

There must be an easy solution like in the JSF world, but i suspect i am looking for the wrong name in the Spring world! :)

Any help is greatly appreciated, this is the last thing I need to fix in my project!

Comment: Can you boil down your problem statement to 3 lines?

Comment: like the title says. I want to share a variable between spring beans, like you can do with jsf and it's application scoped beans.